# How to get average with mongoose in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, average

I create this schema and i want to calculate average loginTime in last day

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var logSchema= new Schema({
     email: {type:String,required:true},
     loginTime: {type:String,required:true},
     loginDate: {type:Date,required:true}
});

var log= mongoose.model('Log',logSchema);

module.exports = log;
```

i use this code but it doens't work.What can i use for this

```
 var Log= require('../models/log');
   function calculateLogTime(time){
    var current_date = new Date();
    var formattedDate = simpleDate.format(current_date, 'dashed');
    Log.average({loginDate:formattedDate},{$avg:'$loginTime'},function(err,count){
        console.log( "Avarage", count );          
        time(count);
     });
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I have this error: Log.average is not function. I looked    
 .avarege function but ı did not find anything